# Tool to download from premium websites

Tags: gratis, survey

I'm looking for a website/program that would allow me to download files from websites without paying / filling in surveys such as with fileice.

I would like it to be:

- free
- MUST download from fileice
- quick (no bandwith limitations)

**I should be able to download / use the tool without having to complete a survey**

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you can use [FileIce Downloader](http://fileicedownloader.co.nr/):

- download from fileice
- quick
- bypass surveys ( uses Java Script to bypass the gateway protection.)
- there seems to be a 30-day trial, not sure if it's free afterward.

I haven't tried it myself so no idea whether it works or contains adwares.

Comment: Unfortunately, it requires you to complete a survey to download it...

Comment: You mean, to download FileIce Downloader?

Comment: Yes I do mean that

Comment: Why the downvote? If you tried the tool and had a bad experience with it, let us know...

Comment: **Yes, tell us!** Don't downvote without a comment!! @Franck I think they might have downvoted because it requires survey to download, which I want to avoid...?

Comment: Maybe :/ in which case I guess we can find some mirrors without any survey.

Comment: have you found any mirrors?